# Android - How to set a named method in button.setOnClickListener()

Tags: java, android, event-handling

Most samples that I see appear to use an anonymous method in a call like button.setOnClickListener().  Instead, I'd like to pass in a method defined on the Activity class that I'm working in.  What's the Java/Android equivalent of the following event handler wiring in C#?

```
Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.Click += this.OnMyButtonClick;
```

Where:

```
private void OnMyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
}
```

Essentially, I'd like to reuse a non-anonymous method to handle the click event of multiple buttons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Roman Nurik's answer is almost correct. View.OnClickListener() is actually an interface. So if your Activity implements OnClickListener, you can set it as the button click handler.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

      public void onCreate() {
           button.setOnClickListener(this);
           button2.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      public void onClick(View v) {
           //Handle based on which view was clicked.
      }
}
```

There aren't delegates as in .Net, so you're stuck using the function based on the interface. In .Net you can specify a different function through the use of delegates.

Comment: I didn't realize that Java didn't have a delegate type - thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I actually just came across this article (it's actually an old article). Somewhat interesting comments about their decission not to use delegates. I don't know if I agree because I loved using delegates in .Net. http://java.sun.com/docs/white/delegates.html

Answer (score 9):

The argument to `View.setOnClickListener` must be an instance of the class `View.OnClickListener` (an inner class of the `View` class).. For your use case, you can keep an instance of this inner class in a variable and then pass that in, like so:

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something here
    }
};

myButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
myButton2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

If you need this listener across multiple subroutines/methods, you can store it as a member variable in your activity class.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the method will need to be this...

```
public void onMyButtonClick(View view){

}
```

If you are not using dynamic buttons, you can set the "onClick" event from the designer to "onMyButtonClick".  That's how I do it for static buttons on a screen.  It was easier for me to relate it to C#.

Comment: Note that this is new to Android 1.6, IIRC.