# this keyword accepted in onClick(View v) method

Tags: java, android, interface

I'm new to **Android** environment I'm just wondering why does the `OnClick(View v)` method accepts `this` if the required parameter is in type `View` and my method extends `Activity`? Is there a relationship between `View` and `Activity`? Please refer to the code to make the question clearer.

```
...
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn1;
    private Button btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ...
        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        // Below are the methods calling which confuses me
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        ...
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.get();
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.button1:
                //statement for button1
            case R.id.button2:
                //statement for button2
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:This question is misleading, just caused by overlooking 'setOnClickListener(...)' is the same as 'onClick(...)'. I just don't know how to close this question.

Comment: learn some java basics ... do you even know what are the interfaces? you are not calling OnClick(this) but setOnClickListener which accepts OnClickListener interface ...

Comment: This may also be useful...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners

Comment: I see now onClick is a method of setOnClickListener. Thanks @Selvin

Comment: @gihooh No, it is not. onClick is not a method of setOnClickListener. onClick is a method from the onClickListener interface. setOnClickListener is a method in the Button class, which sets a listener that should be triggered when a click event occurs. I **strongly recommend you to learn the java basics**.

Comment: I see I copy pasted the wrong word from the comment above. Thanks anyway for the advice @1337.

Comment: @gihooh **The parameter has to be an instance of some object that implements the OnClickListener interface** see [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25059146/991085) and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972579/android-how-to-set-a-named-method-in-button-setonclicklistener

Answer (score 2):

Look,

**Understand This Two Lines First**

```
View.OnClickListener - Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.
onClick() - Called when a view has been clicked.
```

Now,
Your Activity is **Implementing `OnClickListener`**

> 

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{}
```

> 

So When you implement that... there is a **method automatically implemented to class** called `onClick()`

So when you pass `this` keyword to `onClickListener` of Any view. it means **you are actually calling `onClick()` Method..**

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(this); //calling onClick() method for button1
btn2.setOnClickListener(this); //calling onClick() method for button2
```

in `onClick()` method,
you just have to find your ID and write code for what you want to do with the view..

```
public void onClick(View v){
int id=v.get(); // getting ID of Clicked View

switch(id){

case R.id.button1:
    //called when you press button 1
    //write your code 
    break;
case R.id.button2:
    //called when you press button 2
    //write your code 
    break;
...
}
```

Please visit this website/blog for more detail about onClickListener()
https://stand2code.blogspot.in/2016/12/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android.html

Comment: Thank you brother for the effort very well said. But I just overlooked the code thinking that `OnClickListener` interface == `setOnClickListener(...)` == `onClick(...)`. Anyway is there a way to remove this post because I think it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending `Activity` but you are implementing `OnClickListener` too,and `onClick()` is a method of `OnClickListener`interface.Hence you have to implement its `onClick` method in your `class` and thus `this` is not raising any conflict.See this to learn about interfaces [Is there more to an interface than having the correct methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504904/how-are-java-interfaces-actually-used)

Answer (score 0):

`setOnClickListener` take an `OnClickListener` instance as parameter and `OnClickListener` is an interface which content an `onClick()` method.

**The parameter has to be an instance of some object that implements the OnClickListener interface**  as you are passing here `setOnClickListener(this);` current context.

For more info see : [Android - How to set a named method in button.setOnClickListener()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972579/android-how-to-set-a-named-method-in-button-setonclicklistener)